# How to fade a part of an object or image in corona sdk when move it?

Tags: object, lua, hide, coronasdk, fade

I have a question in corona sdk. I need to fade top part of an object (like 60px of 250px) when moving the object to top before it goes out of the screen.

In another word, I need to set a display area for an image or object which its height is more than screen height. Like a top padding space which image will be faded when moving out of the display area (not the screen area)

Any tutorial or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like image masks are exactly what you need.
In your case you would need to set the mask when moving the object to top, unset it when it comes back.

You can check the documentation for masks here:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/imageMask/index.html

Comment: I posted another question. would you please help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324973/how-to-create-move-and-remove-dynamic-objects-in-corona-sdk